# executing create plpgsql function in vscode runs properly only if selecting the all function definition lines

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, plpgsql, sqltools

I'm using vscode version 1.74.2 with SQLTools extension v0.26.0 in order to work with a postgresql 15 database.

when i'm writing a plpgsql function, the editor marks in color the function besides the last line of `END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

SQLTools provides the shortcut called `SQLTools Connection: Run current query`

i can't use it because i get unterminated quoted string error.

as you can see in the following screenshot it marks only the 3 first lines when i go with the keyboard cursor over the function definition:

[image: cursor over plpgsql create function]

so when I try to execute the `run current query` shortcut i get the following error:

```
unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
BEGIN
 return query select 1::int;" at character 61
```

of course if i manually mark all the 4 lines and then run the query it creates the function properly, but this is very annoying since this is an example and i deal with complex functions and to start marking all of them in order to execute them each time is a hassle.

any ideas how i can resolve this ?

Comment: File an issue with the VSCode/SQLTools developers. The problem is on their end.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - thank i filed an issue, i'll update here what they respond

Comment: well.. no response yet, but just in case i'm posting my issue here: https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/1071